# Why does Ruby give this large precision decimal result?

Tags: ruby

I want to convert a subtitle time code:

```
begin="00:00:07.71" dur="00:00:03.67
```

to pure seconds:

```
begin=7.1 end=11.38
```

I wrote a Ruby code:

```
def to_sec(value)
        a = value.split(':')
        a[0].to_i*3600+a[1].to_i*60+a[2].to_f
    end
```

which resulted in `11.379999999999999`.
Can anybody tell me why this happens?
Is there any Time library that can do this conversion?

Comment: That’s due to the way floating point numbers are stored. [Google for „what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic“](http://www.google.com/search?q=what%20every%20computer%20scientist%20should%20know%20about%20floating-point%20arithmetic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll probably be easiest for you to represent your underlying datatype as integer hundredths of a second (centiseconds):

```
     def to_csec(value) #if you had CSec < Integer this would be `def self.[](value)`
        a = value.split(':')
        #tacking on a couple zeros to each
        a[0].to_i*360000+a[1].to_i*6000+(a[2].to_f * 100).to_i
     end
```

You could add some helpers for dealing with the durations and pretty printing them as well:

```
     def csec_to_s(csec) #if you had CSec < Integer, this would be `def to_sec`
        "%.2f" % (csec.to_f / 100)
     end

    class SubtitleDuration < Range
     def initialize(a,b)
        centi_a = to_csec(a)
        super(centi_a,to_csec(b) + centi_a)
     end
     def to_s
       "begin=#{csec_to_s(self.begin)} end=#{csec_to_s(self.end) }"
     end
    end
```

Then your answer is just:

```
    puts SubtitleDuration.new("00:00:07.71", "00:00:03.67").to_s 
    #=> begin=7.71 end=11.38
```

Comment: Wouldn't thirtieths of a second be more applicable in this case, rather than hundredths?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Sorry, I'm a bit confused by your question. How does one accurately represent 0.71 in thirtieths? 21.3/30? Are thirtieths what he's actually getting out of his process and the problem data are misrepresented or where are you coming from on this?

Comment: Snowwhite: I thought there were thirty frames in a second. The OP might know better, though.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing can happen in just about any programming language.  It's because of how floating point numbers are represented.  They're not stored as decimals under the hood, so sometimes you get odd rounding errors like this.